# How to read files in a directory?

Tags: c++, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I need to read some files from a directory and the `std::filesystem` does not seems to work. I already tried `std::experimental::filesystem` but I get the same error  `‘std::filesystem’ has not been declared` respectively  `‘std::experimental::filesystem’ has not been declared`. Is there any other way to read files?

```
std::vector<std::string> get_folder_content(std::string path)
{
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    std::filesystem::directory_iterator path_iterator(path);
    for (const auto& entry : path_iterator)
    {
        files.push_back(entry.path().string());
    }
    return files;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377867/how-to-read-files-in-a-directory?/) by [anonymous74063](https://answers.ros.org/users/74063/anonymous74063/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2021-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-05-07**:
I'm sorry to close your question, especially since it already has an answer, but this is not a ROS question. It's a general C++ question. Please keep your ROS Answers questions *on topic*, meaning: they should ask questions about ROS.

For all other questions (about programming, robotics, math, etc), try to find an appropriate forum, such as Stack Overflow, the Ubuntu fora, Robotics Stack Exchange, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this c++ implementation of the glob function some time ago and have been using it since:

> std::vectorstd::string glob(const std::string& pattern) {
> using namespace std;
>
> // glob struct resides on the stack
> glob_t glob_result;
> memset(&glob_result, 0,
> sizeof(glob_result));
>
> // do the glob operation   int
> return_value = glob(pattern.c_str(),
> GLOB_TILDE, NULL, &glob_result);   if
> (return_value != 0) {
> globfree(&glob_result);
> stringstream ss;
> ss << "glob() failed with return_value " << return_value <<
> endl;
> throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());   }
>
> // collect all the filenames into a
> std::liststd::string
> vector filenames;   for
> (size_t i = 0; i <
> glob_result.gl_pathc; ++i) {
> filenames.push_back(string(glob_result.gl_pathv[i]));
> }   // cleanup
> globfree(&glob_result);   // done
> return filenames; }

You can call this function as:

> filenames = glob("/*.");

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2021-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous74063](https://answers.ros.org/users/74063/anonymous74063/) on 2021-05-06**:
Thanks I gonna try it out.